# I can't add text to "Message" in VS Code when committing to Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When I try to commit in VS Code it fails after a bit saying:

[image]

In VS Code, I click "Commit" but then I can't type anything in the box.  The cursor goes up there, but does not allow me to type.  Any ideas?

[image]

A COMMIT_EDITMSG document opens but nothing changes. I did try changing it, but it doesn’t help.

I check the output and Git logs a lot but all is info, no errors:

[image]

Comment: type the commit command on the terminal